# scrolling in the bottom is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am using a web view its working fine. but I am having a three issue 1.i want to change the font 2. change the size of font 3. when I scroll the web content to bottom it's not scrolling up to the bottom.

```
content=[[UIWebView alloc]init];
content.Frame=CGRectMake(10, 200, 300, 480);
[content loadHTMLString:content1 baseURL:nil];
[content loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body background-colo r: transparent text=\"#eadfa8\" font-family=\"Arial Rounded MT Bold\" font-size=\".1\">%@</body></html>", [self.JSONData  objectForKey:@"content"]] baseURL: nil];
[content stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"content.body.style.fontFamily = 'Arial'"];
content.opaque=YES;
[self.view addSubview:content];
[content setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[content setOpaque:NO];
```

above html coding I try to change the font family to Arial but its not working. help me .

Comment: what is different between `content` and `self.content` ? why you are loading `loadHTMLString` two times ??

Comment: sorry only content only appear there. content is a webview.

Comment: i am just try above code. i am new to ios.

Comment: Pls check your webview frame content.Frame=CGRectMake(10, 200, 300, 480);

Comment: NANNAV- than you so much for your idea.i change my frame its work fine.

Answer (score 0):

For First two issues answer is [Font change inside UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533445/how-to-change-uiwebview-default-font)

The third issue you can overcome by below lines

```
content.scalesPageToFit=TRUE;
content.scrollView.bounces = NO;
```

Comment: i add that above coding but scroll is not working in side the web view why?