# How to get the UIWebView's equivalent of the iOS 8 system font?

Tags: ios, ios7, fonts, ios8, uiwebview

I am trying to use the very same font in a UIWebView on iOS that the iOS system uses currently.

This means I want to use the very same font I'd get from:

```
UIFontDescriptor *fd;
fd = [UIFontDescriptor preferredFontDescriptorWithTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:fd size:0];
```

There are lots of answers on SO ([iPhone Development - Setting UIWebView font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449773/iphone-development-setting-uiwebview-font), [Using custom font in a UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490696/using-custom-font-in-a-uiwebview), [How to change UIWebView default font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533445/how-to-change-uiwebview-default-font), [How to set custom font in UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768203/how-to-set-custom-font-in-uiwebview)) that explain how to embed a UIFont's familyName or fontName into an html's style attributes, by doing this:

```
NSString *fontStyle, *htmlString = @"test";
fontStyle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"font-family:%@;font-size:%d", font.familyName, (int)font.pointSize];
htmlString = NSString stringWithFormat:@"<span style=\"%@\">%@</span>", fontStyle, htmlString];
```

But this doesn't seem to work on iOS 7 and 8 any more where these system font names are now like:

```
font.fontName: .HelveticaNeueInterface-Regular
font.familyName: .Helvetica Neue Interface
```

When using these names in an UIWebView with the "font-family" attribute, the text gets rendered in the default font (which is with serifs and certainly not the new iOS system font). Removing the leading period doesn't help, either.

So, how do I now translate the system's font into a name that gets correctly interpreted by the Web Kit?

Please understand that I am seeking for a generic solution and do not simply seek the iOS 7/8 name I can insert manually into the html style attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran into [this blog article](http://blog.curtisherbert.com/get-your-app-ready-for-ios-9/) which may offer the solution though I have not verified it yet:

> If you're trying to reference the system font in web views just prepend `-apple-system` to your font-family list and it'll use SF in iOS 9 and Helvetica in older versions.

Which means that the font line of above code needs to be change to:

```
fontStyle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"font-family:-apple-system,Helvetica Neue;font-size:%d", (int)font.pointSize];
```

That should take care of selecting the system font from iOS 7 onward.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Helvetica or San Francisco with attaching font files?

Comment: I don't see how this is helpful to my question.